# How to add value in a text area from a textbox?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have an html page in which I have a textbox (Type your text) in which I need to type in text like this:

```
Name=Value
```

This textbox will be used by the user to quickly add Name Value pairs to the list which is just below that textbox. let's say if we type `Hello=World` in the above textbox and click add, then in the below list, it should show as

```
Hello=World
```

And if we again type `ABC=PQR` in the same textbox, then in the below list, it should show like this so that means it should keep adding new Name Value pair just below its original entry.

```
Hello=World
ABC=PQR
```

But if the syntax is incorrect like if it is not in Name=Value pair then it should not add anything to the list and instead show a pop up that wrong input format. Names and Values can contain only alpha-numeric characters.

Here is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oocgkuh6/6/) what I have tried so far but I am not able to add and sort so far as I am not able to understand how to do this feature? I need to plain HTML and Javascript, I don't want to use any library yet as I want to keep it simple.

Below is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #my-text-box {
            font-size: 18px;
            height: 1.5em;
            width: 585px;
        }
        textarea{
            width:585px;
            height:300px;
        }
        .form-section{
            overflow:hidden;
            width:700px;
        }
        .fleft{float:left}
        .fright{float:left; padding-left:15px;}
        .fright button{display:block; margin-bottom:10px;}
    </style>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function addtext() {
        var newtext = document.form-section.my-text-box.value;
        document.form-section.outputtext.value += newtext;
    }
    </script>       
</head>

<body>
    <h3>Test</h3>

    <label for="pair">Type your text</label></br>
    <div class="form-section">
        <div class="fleft">
            <input type='text' id='my-text-box' name='my-text-box' value="Name=Value" />
        </div>
        <div class="fright">
            <button type="button" onClick="addtext();">Add</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    </br>
    </br>
    </br>

    <label for="pairs">Name/Value Pair List</label></br>
    <div class="form-section">
        <div class="fleft">
            <textarea name='outputtext'>After clicking add button, it should show Name Value pair here</textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="fright">
            <button type="button">Sort by name</button>
            <button type="button">Sort by value</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You forgot to post the JavaScript that doesn't work in both your question and fiddle.

Comment: And your javascript is...?

Comment: just updated with broken stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('add').onclick = addtext;

function addtext() {
    var nameValue = document.getElementById('my-text-box').value;
    if (/^([a-zA-Z0-9]+=[a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/.test(nameValue))
        document.getElementById('output').textContent += nameValue + '\n';
    else
        alert('Bad value.');
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oocgkuh6/8/)