# not able to sort entries in textarea basis on key and value both using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sorting

I have an html page in which I have a textbox (Type your text) and TextArea list. I need to type into the textbox and then click Add button so that whatever is there in textbox goes to my TextArea list. I need to type in this below format in the textbox.

```
Name=Value
```

This textbox will be used by the user to quickly add Name Value pairs to the list which is just below that textbox. let's say if we type `Hello=World` in the above textbox and click add, then in the below list, it should show as

```
Hello=World
```

And if we again type `ABC=PQR` in the same textbox, then in the below list, it should show like this so that means it should keep adding new Name Value pair just below its original entry.

```
Hello=World
ABC=PQR
```

But if the syntax is incorrect like if it is not in Name=Value pair then it should not add anything to the list and instead show a pop up that wrong input format. Names and Values can contain only alpha-numeric characters. Now I have all above things working fine without any issues.

I also have two more buttons `Sort by name` and `Sort by value`. Once I click either of these two buttons, then it should sort entries in TextArea list using either name or value. Is this possible to do using Javascript? I tried adding two methods `sortByKey` and `sortByValue` as I am using split, sort and join methods but its not working as expected and something is getting messed up.

Here is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oocgkuh6/13/). I need to use plain HTML and Javascript, I don't want to use any library yet as I want to keep it simple as I am still learning. What wrong I am doing here?

Below is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Test</title>

<style type="text/css">
    #my-text-box {
        font-size: 18px;
        height: 1.5em;
        width: 585px;
    }
    textarea{
        width:585px;
        height:300px;
    }
    .form-section{
        overflow:hidden;
        width:700px;
    }
    .fleft{float:left}
    .fright{float:left; padding-left:15px;}
    .fright button{display:block; margin-bottom:10px;}
</style>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('add').onclick = addtext;
    function addtext() {
        var nameValue = document.getElementById('my-text-box').value;
        if (/^([a-zA-Z0-9]+=[a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/.test(nameValue))
            document.getElementById('output').textContent += nameValue + '\n';
        else
            alert('Incorrect Name Value pair format.');
    }

    document.getElementById('sortbykey').onclick = sortByKey;
    function sortByKey() {
        var textarea = document.getElementById("output");
        textarea.value = textarea.key.split("=").sort().join("\n");
    }

    document.getElementById('sortbyvalue').onclick = sortByValue;
    function sortByValue() {
        var textarea = document.getElementById("output");
        textarea.value = textarea.value.split("=").sort().join("\n");
    }
</script>

</head>

<body>
<h3>Test</h3>

<label for="pair">Name/Value Pair</label></br>
<div class="form-section">
    <div class="fleft">
        <input type='text' id='my-text-box' value="Name=Value" />
    </div>
    <div class="fright">
        <button type="button" id='add' onclick='addtext()'>Add</button>
    </div>
</div>

</br>
</br>
</br>

<label for="pairs">Name/Value Pair List</label></br>
<div class="form-section">
    <div class="fleft">
       <textarea id='output'></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="fright">
        <button type="button" id='sortbykey' onclick='sortByKey()'>Sort by name</button>
        <button type="button" id='sortbyvalue' onclick='sortByValue()'>Sort by value</button>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How's this different from your last question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32417786/how-to-add-value-in-a-text-area-from-a-textbox-and-then-sort-it)?

Comment: I edited my question to have only add feature but I didn't remove it from title. In this I am specifically focusing on sorting and somehow its not working with my code.

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: sortByValue is not defined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split your `textarea` by lines and then `split` each line to be able to compare either name or value. Right now, you're only splitting once.

So the sequence should be:

- `split` your lines in an `array` - you only need to replace `('=')` with `('\n')`.
- for each line you compare either the `name` or the `value` - these can be done in `sort`. `Sort` will already go through your line `array` and allows you to define which element you want to compare.

You can do it like this:

```
function sortByKey() {
    var textarea = document.getElementById("output");
    textarea.value = textarea.value.split("\n").sort(function(a, b){
        if(a != "" && b != ""){//this because you have empty lines to handle
            return a.split('=')[0].localeCompare(b.split('=')[0])
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }).join("\n");
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/56hs2nmn/

To sort by value, you simply use `a.split('=')[1].localeCompare(b.split('=')[1])`.

You'll see that sort by value and by key is almost exactly the same, you should try to optimize by having only one `function` for both. And also clarify the steps by using variables instead of throwing it all in one line. But it should put you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks Julien. It works as expected and I understood what you explained as well. Appreciated your help. Also if I add a Delete button as well just below `Sort by Value` button and that button has to delete whatever row I am selecting, just like if I selected `Hello=World` then it should delete that. Basically, when the `Delete` button is pressed all selected items in the listbox should be deleted. Do you know by any chance how we can do this?

Comment: You can use Selection() object. Simplest wat would be deleteFromDocument, but I'm not sure it's compatible with all browser. But there's other way, you can remove node of selection for example, etc. With deleteFromDocument: https://jsfiddle.net/56hs2nmn/10/

Answer (score 1):

This could work

https://jsfiddle.net/68cp72s6/

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

    var dom = getDom(["user", "output", "add", "sortbykey", "sortbyvalue"], {});
    var rx = /[\w]+=[\w]+/;
    var model = [];

    function add() {
        var input = dom.user.value;
        if (!rx.test(input)) return;
        var split = input.split("=");
        var obj = { key: split[0], val: split[1] };
        model.push(obj);
        viewModel(model);
    }

    function viewModel(input) {
        var data = JSON.stringify(input, null, 2);
        dom.output.value = data;
    }

    function getDom(arr, tmp) {
        arr.forEach(function(s) {
            tmp[s] = document.getElementById(s);
        });
        return tmp;
    }

    function sorter(prop) {
        return function() {
            var sorted = model.sort(function(a, b) {
                if (a[prop] < b[prop]) return -1;
                if (a[prop] > b[prop]) return 1;
            });
            viewModel(sorted);            
        }
    }

    dom.add.addEventListener("click", add);  
    dom.sortbykey.addEventListener("click", sorter("key"));
    dom.sortbyvalue.addEventListener("click", sorter("val"));

})();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I don't want to make this in JSON, I want to keep it in the format I already have. Like `Name=Value` pair only. Is there any way we can do that using the same format I have? I thought it should be easy to do this. What wrong I am doing in my code?

Comment: It works like a charm. Thanks a lot. It looks like you removed my add method and made some new method for it. In my original `Add` method I had check that only `Name=Value` pair format can be added and Names and Values can contain only alpha-numeric characters. So Now if I need to do the same thing in your method then how will I be doing it. In my original method I was showing alert box if anyone types invalid format.

Comment: @user1950349 that wouldn't be hard to add, it's all about separating concerns.